# How can I check instanceof without the proto chain in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

How can I check instanceof without the proto chain in javascript?

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Foo = function(){

};
Foo.prototype = EventEmitter.prototype;

var Bar = function(){

};
Bar.prototype = EventEmitter.prototype;

var f = new Foo();
var b = new Bar();

f instanceof Foo; //returns true
b instanceof Bar; //returns true

f instanceof Bar; //returns true
b instanceof Foo; //returns true
```

Essentially, I want those last two lines to return false. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#Summary) check,

```
f instanceof Foo
```

it will take the internal `[[prototype]]` object (which can be accessed with [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)) and find if it occurs anywhere in the `Foo`'s prototype chain, till it finds `Object` along the line.

Another important point to be noted here is, `Foo.prototype` is the same as `Bar.prototype`. Because you assign the same object to both the properties. You can confirm this like this

```
console.log(Foo.prototype === Bar.prototype);
// true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(f) === Object.getPrototypeOf(b));
// true
```

That is why all the `instanceof` checks you made in the question return `true`.

To fix this, you need to create the prototype Objects, based on `EventEmitter`'s prototype (not with it). You can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to do that for you. It takes an object, which should be used as the prototype of the newly constructed object.

```
Foo.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
...
Bar.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
```

with this change,

```
console.log(Foo.prototype === Bar.prototype);
// false
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(f) === Object.getPrototypeOf(b));
// false
console.log(f instanceof Foo);
// true
console.log(b instanceof Bar);
// true
console.log(f instanceof Bar);
// false
console.log(b instanceof Foo);
// false
```