# Object.create() instead of prototype

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm reading through Crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts". Early on he introduces the `Object.create()` function, and it seems to be redundant. Why is `Object.create()` preferred to assigning an object to the prototype of a new object the good ol' fashioned way? What's the difference between these two statements? I certainly prefer the `Object.create()` syntax, but I'd like to understand the fundamentals here:

```
var bar = Object.create(foo);
```

and

```
var bar = {};
bar.prototype = foo;
```

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28912291/1903116) helps.

Comment: Your second example should be `var bar = {}; bar.__proto__ = foo;`.

Answer (score 1):

How it works is ,

```
function createObject(proto) {
    function ctor() { }

    // assigns prototype of Person to ctor's prototype
    ctor.prototype = proto;

    // return new instance of ctor
    return new ctor();
}

// Usage:
Student.prototype = createObject(Person.prototype);
```

So, it creates new object constructor with prototype assigned as prototype of Person.

When you try to add a new function in Student's prototype object, it is not available in Person's prototype

ex -

```
Student.prototype = createObject(Person.prototype);

Student.prototype.newFunc1 = function() { console.log('hello from new world');}

//Person.prototype will not have newFunc1.
```

In case of where you directs assigns prototype of Person to prototype of Student like

And when you add a new function into prototype of Student like

```
Student.prototype = Person.prototype;

Student.prototype.newFunc1 = function() { console.log('hello from new world');}

//When you check Person.prototype, it will have newFunc1 function.
```

> prototype object is not assigned, only the reference is assigned.

In object oriented programming, the child class has properties of parent as well as its own.

If we don't do Object.create() and directly assign prototype of parent to the prototype of child , whatever new property we add to the child, will get reflected in parent too.

To avoid that, Object.create() is preferred.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. As what is at issue is why `Object.create(proto)` should be used rather than directly creating a `Object` and setting its prototype to `proto`, not the issue that the prototype of a constructor should be a new object with the same prototype as its parent and not the parent's prototype.